# Animate one line of elements, with different hover tags

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-animations, keyframe

**I've got a username and a password section when the user hovers over the text input area, the correlating text is animated with a little bounce.**

To reduce duplicating code I tried to combine it using the ',' selector. however, this meant that the .password-field and the .password also animate when the user hovers over .user-field.

```
        .user-field:hover ~ .user , .password-field:hover ~ .password {
            animation-name: boing;
            animation-duration: 2s;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        }
```

Is there any way to do this without causing the second half to be animated on the first hover?

Comment: Better try child concept. (last-child:hover)

Answer (score 0):

**The issue wasn't the CSS applying the animation linearly.**

The issue was due to my first and third grid being auto. The auto meant when the margin for the element inside the grid changed, it changed the size of the grid. As the size changed it pushed the division smaller and made it look like the other elements were moving at the same time.

TL;DR It was fixed when the auto was changed to a percentage.